# Get Windows local group name by SID

Tags: c++

I want to get the name of a local group from SID and then put it in a variable and then add a user to that group.

I've already tried this but I don't get any output, expecting the group name:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>
#include <lmcons.h>
#include <lmaccess.h>
#include <lmerr.h>
#include <lmapibuf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Sddl.h>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")

static const DWORD MAX_BUFF_SIZE = 256;

std::wstring userNameFromSid()
{

    PSID psid = NULL;

    BOOL bSucceeded = ConvertStringSidToSid(TEXT("S-1-5-32-544"), &psid);
    if (bSucceeded == FALSE) {
        cout<<("Error Converting SID to String");
    }

    wchar_t buffName[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    DWORD buffNameSize = MAX_BUFF_SIZE;
    wchar_t buffDomain[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    DWORD buffDomainSize = MAX_BUFF_SIZE;
    SID_NAME_USE SidType = SidTypeGroup;

    if (LookupAccountSid(NULL, psid, buffName, &buffNameSize, NULL, &buffDomainSize, &SidType))
    {
        cout<<("group name %ws\n", buffName);
        getch();
        return buffName;
    }
    cout<<("Error code: %d", GetLastError());


    //LocalFree(psid);

    /*Here some code to print error in a Message box*/
    return L"";
}
int main()
{
    NET_API_STATUS err = 0;
    userNameFromSid();
    return(0);
}
```

I'm not sure if I can add user to a group with SID (without using Group name like Administrators), but if that's possible, then it will do the job.

Comment: "I don't get any output"  - what does the `printf` of `GetLastError` display?  (do you need a `getch` after it?)  If that printf is never called, where does the program stop?  I suggest stepping through with a debugger.

Comment: I assume you have compiled this with UNICODE set?  Also, given you always use wide chars (rather than the abortion known as tchar), you can get a wide char string literal with `L"S-1-5-32-544"` rather than having to use `TEXT`.

Comment: @MartinBonner Changed the printf to cout and updated the code. I assume nothing. Im defining UNICODE on the code. Im using G++ to compile. Dont know if it uses Unicode or UTF-8 to compile by default.

Comment: @MartinBonner I changed `TEXT` to `L""` but still no output.
here is the warning i get from g++:
`getnamefromsid.cpp: In function 'std::__cxx11::wstring userNameFromSid()':

getnamefromsid.cpp:30:67: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'LPWSTR' {aka 'wchar_t*'} [-Wwrite-strings]
     
BOOL bSucceeded = ConvertStringSidToSid(L"S-1-5-32-544", &psid);`

Comment: Err, that warning got mangled by SO.  You'll need to fix the \`foo' to 'foo'

Comment: What do you think `cout<<("Error code: %d", GetLastError());` will do?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think if the SID dont match and cant get it, then it will throw an error.

Comment: Try `wchar_t tsid[] = L"S-1-5-32-544"; ` and then pass `tsid` to `ConvertStringSidToSid`.  That will suppress the warning and might fix the problem.

Comment: @AriaFathi There is **NOTHING** in your code which will throw.

Comment: And `"Error code: %d"` will just be discarded, just like in `cout<<("group name %ws\n", buffName);` - but there you actually stream a `wchar_t[]` to `cout`...

Comment: The `("Error code: %d", GetLastError())` uses the comma operator and gcc will warn that the expression `"Error code: %d"` has no side effects.  It should still print the output from GetLastError though.  (You probably wanted `std::cout << "Error code: "  << GetLastError() << std::endl;` - I don't know why you bothered changing from printf)

Comment: @MartinBonner Warning is gone now. What do you mean there is nothing to throw? The code dont have any outputs?

Comment: So you mean its getting the name but the cout is the issue here?

Comment: There is no `throw` statement in your code and no call to a function which can throw.  (Not quite true, `ostream::operator <<` can throw, but it won't in this case.)

Comment: *What does your debugger say*

Comment: @MartinBonner VS2019 debugger throws an exception on the `LookupAccountSid`:
`Exception thrown at 0x77196494 (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.`

Comment: OK.  So the only NULL pointer you are passing is for the first argument, and that is clearly correct.  I notice that even if ConvertStringSidToSid fails you plough on.  Did it succeed?  If not, why not?

Comment: @MartinBonner I checked the variables in debugger and value of `buffName` is `0x0116f4e8 L"Administrators"` and `psid` is `0x01608578`. Yea I guess it will continue on because there is no break out if fails.